# Print stylesheet not showing inline images

Tags: xhtml, printing, image

I have a weird problem where printing on Firefox displays all the  items in the content, but it's not working on other browsers. In all the other browsers (IE9/8, Chrome, Safari) the images are not showing at all. These are inline items, not CSS background images.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether the "Print Background Colors and Images" checkbox (Tools/Print/Page Setup) is ticked? If it's not ticked, inline images won't be displayed.

Sorry, previous post contained that info, but was rejected. The menu option I refer to above is IE9 (9.0.8112.16421, Update 9.0.4)

Comment: What browser and OS are you referring to?

Comment: Ok, I found the option, which was not exactly at the menu path you mentioned above. So that's IE, but my problem extents to other browsers too unfortunately.